# Solr WhitespaceTokenizerFactory - \r\n not seen as whitespace?

Tags: java, solr

The prepackaged WhitespaceTokenizerFactory is not acting as I would anticipate.  I am able to achieve the desired results by using a combination of the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory and various PatternReplaceFilterFactory, but I'm curious why \r\n is being seen as literal characters instead of a character return and line feed.  Any guidance that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Initial String:

```
Daniel, \r\n\r\n This is a test.
OR
Daniel,\r\n\r\nThis is a test.
```

Solr Analysis:

```
WT  text    Daniel, \r\n\r\n    This    is  a   test.
    raw_bytes   [44 61 6e 69 65 6c 2c]  [5c 72 5c 6e 5c 72 5c 6e]   [54 68 69 73]   [69 73] [61]    [74 65 73 74 2e]
    start   0   8   17  22  25  27
    end 7   16  21  24  26  32
    positionLength  1   1   1   1   1   1
    type    word    word    word    word    word    word
    position    1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Desired Result:

```
[Daniel,] [This] [is] [a] [test.]
```

Solr Field Type:

```
<fieldType name="text_classic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
 <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Solr Field Name:

```
<field name="test_field" type="text_classic" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

Solr Version:

6.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happens exactly, but you can use [CharFilterFactories](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories) to achieve what you are looking for. A quote from the documentation :-

> Char Filters can be chained like Token Filters and placed in front of a Tokenizer. Char Filters can add, change, or remove characters while preserving the original character offsets to support features like highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for your help!